# Using fetch command resulted in 'URLSearchParams' in self not defined

Tags: node.js, fetch-api

I wrote an javascript programme:

```
const fetch = require('whatwg-fetch');
const requestEndpoint = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2';
const Yelp = {
searchYelp(){
   var myInit = {
        method: 'GET'
}
return fetch(requestEndpoint, myInit).then(response => {
  return response.json();}).then(jsonResponse =>{
      console.log(jsonResponse)}).catch(err => 
         console.log(`Error: ${err}`));
}};
```

On edit, an error result in 'URLSearchParams' in self not defined, why?

Please help!

Comment: Hey @Mendel, welcome to StackOverflow, a couple of rules:
1. Please specify more information such as the version of the packages you're using and the environment of your script.
2. Please make sure to properly format your code - people are likely to help you if they can read the code in question.
3. Try searching on the web a little bit more before posting questions, [here](https://github.com/formio/formio.js/issues/1048) is a link to a Github issue that might be relevant to your problem.

Comment: The whatwg-fetch version that I used is 3.0.0., which is the latest version that I could download.  I should be working in a server environment.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use the [whatwg-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch#browser-support) module?

You could try the [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) module instead.

There doesn't seem to be any good reason for the error you're getting, it happens when you load the module. Is this module designed for use within node.js?

You could try:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const requestEndpoint = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2';

const Yelp = {
    searchYelp() {
        var myInit = {
                method: 'GET'
        }
        return fetch(requestEndpoint, myInit).then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(jsonResponse => {
                console.log(jsonResponse)
        }).catch(err => 
                console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
        );
    }
};

Yelp.searchYelp();
```

Comment: Yep, `whatwg-fetch` is for browsers.